# What are the green digits in the top left of the MS SQL Server Management Studio window?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Not the line numbers - see the large '5' below:

[image]

Every time I run a new query or resize the window, it updates to a new, seemingly random, digit.

[image]

1. What is this?
2. How does one turn it off?

Thanks,

Comment: are you using a 3rd party software over SSMS?

Comment: Really good question - that got me thinking, and turns out it was Nvidia Geforce Experience giving me a 'FPS' counter for Microsoft Sequel Server Management Studio. Uninstalling the Nvidia software removed the counter.

Comment: Well done. You crack it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was Nvidia Geforce Experience giving me a 'FPS' counter for Microsoft Sequel Server Management Studio.

I have not yet seen how to exclude the program from Nvidia Geforce Experience, but - that at least explains what the number was, and uninstalling Nvidia's software removed it.